# TouchSwipe on jQuery list

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have been testing out the TouchSwipe plugin from: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/ and it works just how I want it do to. 
But for some reason its not working on a list-elements that I append from another script file.

Let's see the code from the first file where I make the list:

```
$('#list').append('<li class="test" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">' + response.name + '</li>');
```

And then I include the main.js file where I have all my main functions:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".test").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        if(direction == 'left'){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); 
        } else if(direction == 'right'){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        }

    },
    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
     threshold:0
  });
```

});

The script works fine on list elements that I make straight in the HTML file, but not on the list elements on what I print out from my first file with the responses.

Any idea of what Im missing or doing wrong? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom function to reattach the swipe event to the new elements:

```
$(function() {
    var addSwipeTo = function(selector) {  
         $(selector).swipe("destroy");
         $(selector).swipe({
            //Generic swipe handler for all directions
            swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
              $(this).text("You swiped " + direction );  
            },
             threshold:0
          });
    };
    addSwipeTo(".test");

    $(document).on('click','button',function(){
       $('#list').append('<li class="test" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">New Item</li>');
       addSwipeTo(".test");
    });

});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4CLqY/32/)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, where should I use this? :)

Comment: Thanks for the demo and update :) Im was reading on the docs you first sent. And trying to test this out

Comment: Thanks @Felix! This works great, but now I need to have all this in one file and not in seperate files. But thats no big deal ;)